# Touching my RAM, Freezes Windows, Shutdowns PC

Tags: memory, power-supply, freeze, shutdown

When touching one of the two RAM modules, my Windows freezes and needs force shutdown, and sometimes it just shuts down and restarts by itself immediately. This happens only with one of the two RAM, the right one on the image. It happens when touching the red part and the black part of the RAM.

After trying it out 3 times, just to make sure the RAM is crashing my PC after touching, my screen did not see my PC anymore. I had to force a shutdown, turn off PSU, take out BIOS battery, take out RAM that caused the crash, put the BIOS battery in again, turn on PSU, start PC, now it showed up on my screen. Then turned everything down again, put in the faulty RAM, hoping it would work, and yes it did. PC starts normally again, and I am not going to touch the RAM again.

Why is this happening? Why isn't it happening with the left RAM? I have no further problems with my PC and it is running for a long time without a problem. Then again, I never touched my RAM when the PC was on in the beginning, so I don't know if this is new or was always like this.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: **Stop touching your memory.**  You could seriously damage your PC by doing what you are doing in addition to being incredibly unsafe.  If you suspect a bad memory module then just replace it.

Comment: "Don't touch this" - MC Hammer

Comment: Yes, I should not touch the RAM so much... But do you know why this is happening? I mean, shouldn't it be safe to touch it? Why isn't it happening with the other one? I touched it by mistake when I was moving the power lines for the fan, but after it happened, I wanted to know it was the RAM.

Comment: “But do you know why this is happening?” - You are touching a slotted module with your PC running.  Stop doing that.  “I mean, shouldn't it be safe to touch it?” - I literally just told you it’s extremely dangerous!  Seriously, just stop it.

Comment: Apparently, people don't like when RAM's are touched, seeing the downvotes on my question. Shouldn't it be grounded to avoid these issues? Seeing the other module does not have issues. I mean, if anything is grounded correctly, it should not do this. It's like touching the heat sink block, and your PC restarts, yes that should not happen.

Comment: If you had asked on Electronics.SE or Physics.SE, you might have gotten a decent answer about something like static discharge corrupting the RAM contents or such. I'd have liked to read such an answer. But most of the downvotes are from people who don't care about the science behind why it happens and just enjoy parroting "it's bad because it's bad".

Comment: @grawity That's exactly what I was waiting for, some science behind the issue, but apparently I am on the wrong exchange for that. Thanks for pointing out the other exchanges, where I'll ask something like this the next time.

Comment: "Shouldn't it be grounded to avoid these issues?" - It is, except **you are not grounded**, thus the reason it is dangerous.  "That's exactly what I was waiting for, some science behind the issue, but apparently I am on the wrong exchange for that." - **Electricity + Human Body = Dangerous.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First -

## **Stop doing that, you'll break it.**

Clean the contacts.

Contact cleaner spray, $£€ 5 from any electronics shop.

Power it off first, remove RAM, spray, replace RAM several times to give the contacts an extra scrub, then leave out at least 30 mins. Replace. Power up.

You could run memory tests, but as this is obviously being caused by **touching it whilst it's running** I doubt that the memory is actually bad - or wasn't **until you started touching it while it was running.**

For those demanding the "science" behind it - we will never know.
It may have been static discharge, it may have been poor contact.
Cleaning the contacts & not touching it again will fix both issues.

Comment: Yes, sometimes when the engine needs to be turned on to do maintenance, I put my hand around the engine when it's running, but not where the moving parts are of course.

Comment: So the RAM is not faulty? (Because the other RAM does not have this issue). I thought for such expensive modules, it should at least be static proof from the outside. Or at least, it should be grounded.. :/

Comment: This whole topic sounds so creepy and awkward hehe

Comment: @MOTIVECODEX your computer CASE is what protects it

Comment: Ok ok, I'll stop touching it

Comment: "So the RAM is not faulty?" - It's possible the module is bad, it's possible there is just a dirty pin, not possible to determine based on the information you provided.  When you apply pressure to the module, that is slotted, is causing something to happen with one module that isn't happening with the other.  If you are worried then replace the module.